# Passing MultiValue Parameter to Cascading Parameter in Subreport with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a summary report that passes information to a detail subreport in SSRS. The subreport accepts 4 parameters:

1. From Date (DateTime)
2. To Date (DateTime)
3. District (Multi-value String)
4. Item ID (Multi-value String)

The Item ID parameter is a cascading parameter that depends on the From and To Date. I am having an issue with the parameter not being set when values are passed from the main report to the subreport that are not within that date range. Take the following as an example:

```
Group    Item ID
Banks    ABCD  01
         ABCD  02
         ABCD  03
         ABCD  04
```

The values above are defined in a setup table used in the main report. The idea is that the Banks group should have those Item ID's associated with them. Those values are passed to the subreport via the Item ID parameter. The problem is that when the parameters are passed to the subreport, not all of the Item ID's will necessarily be in the data for the given date range. In this case, SSRS does not select any of the Item IDs when the subreport is loaded.

Some additional information:

- The Item ID parameter needs to be set up as a cascading parameter in this way because there are over a thousand different values and SSRS does not support more than 1,000 items in a multivalued list.
- The table that both reports are using is a transaction table so the queries can be slow. I would like to avoid having to execute another dataset to determine which Item ID's are actually within the date range from the main report (since this is going to happen anyway when the subreport is loaded).
- If all 4 of the Item ID's are available for the given date range in the report, it selects them correctly.

I was thinking it may be possible to create a running value type field that concatenates the Item ID's together to a string in the main report, then split it and pass it to the subreport. This would get the item id's actually used in the query without having to execute the query another time. I thought it may also be possible to trim out the values in the subreport if they aren't contained in the parameter value list? I'm guessing, if this is possible, I will need a hidden parameter to do this work then set the main parameter from the hidden parameter.

Any thoughts on how I can handle this situation? Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I'm facing it now, and I'm thinking the only solutions are 1) Write custom code in the report or 2) include a comma-separated list of multi-select parameter options in the output of my main dataset, so I can set the drill-down parameter with that instead of what was selected in the report parameter.